# Overlaying different plots types in the same figure Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graphics

I need to put both a boxplot and a bar plot in the same graph. 
I have a dataframe like this:

Suppose I recebe the data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(0,1,10), \
                   np.random.normal(0,1,10)],
                  index=["A", "B"])
```

In order to have the index as columns I transpose the df

```
df = df.transpose()
```

Now I want to overlap a box plot with for columns A and  B and a Bar Plot with the mean of each column.

How I can overlap them using **matplotlib** once they are different types?

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the handle for the axes, the plot the second on that axes using `ax=ax`.

```
ax = df.plot.box()
_ = df.T.plot.bar(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am not sure this is the right output. There is only two columns, so the x-axis should have only two labels. Each of x-axis label would show a bar with the mean of that column and a box -plot for the data points of that column.